# Does stripe supports deposite money into customers profile, so that they can use it for future payments?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to add a feature where a customer can deposit his money into his account so that he can use this money for future checkouts.

Suppose a scenario where a customer checks out successfully. But the seller is unable to deliver the product. So it requires a refund of the money back to the customer. The refunded money will be stored in the customer deposit so the customer can use it for future checkouts. If he doesn't need future checkouts, he can withdraw his money. is that possible?

Comment: Why not ask Stripe's developer support about this? Either their documentation contains such details, or it it missing from the documentation, or that is not possible

Answer (score 1):

In Stripe, there is [Customer Balance](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance) feature, but it's limited to so some use cases. You can use the [credit balance API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_balance_transactions/create) to adjust the customer balance. However this feature is built around [Stripe Invoicing and Billing](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance).

Back to your use case, I think one option is to not use [Stripe APIs to refund the customer](https://stripe.com/docs/refunds), but just create a [credit balance adjustment](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance#modifying) to the customer balance which will be applied to the first next invoice by default ([You can't choose what Invoice to apply this balance nor the amount](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance#:%7E:text=You%20can%E2%80%99t%20choose%20a%20specific%20invoice%20to%20apply%20the%20credit%20balance%20to.))

Answer (score 1):

While Stripe doesn't officially support the use of its features for a wallet system like this, it essentially works like a wallet:
-When you receive funds from customers, they get stored on your account balance.
-When you refund payments, funds from your account balance are returned to your customers.

As long as you set your Payout schedule to manual, funds will be kept on your balance.

This is de facto a wallet system not unlike what you're trying to implement.
A notable difference is that Stripe doesn't really intend for you to use this balance in this way, and you are limited in the amount of time you can keep funds on your balance:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-balances#holding-funds

Also, if your account is set in the US/UK, you can top up that balance, but you can't anywhere else:
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/top-ups
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/top-ups/uk

Otherwise, you can only add funds to you balance to cover refunds, which might work for your use-case too.